# Selecting an object from a list based on the name

Tags: c#, linq

I have certain number of objects in a list, I would like to select one object from the list based on the name. I have tried the following code. It doesn't yield any [Enumeration Yielded no results ]. It is bit strange. Could anybody help with this? . My code is below

```
var tableobj = from table in tableOfObjects 
                     where tableOfObjects.ToString().Contains(objName)
                     select table;
```

Here tableOfObjects contains certain number of objects and, objName is to select an object based on the name of the object

Update::::::::::::::::::::::

tableOfObjects contains certain number of class objects it is defined as ListtableOfObjects

Comment: What do you mean by name of object? What do the objects look like?

Comment: tableOfObjects  contains certain number of class objects it is defined as List<Object>tableOfObjects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
   var tableobj = from table in tableOfObjects
                       where table.ToString().Contains(objName)
                       select table;
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use the `typeOf` for checking object.

```
 var tableobj=tableOfObjects.Where(p=>typeOf(p)==typeOf(obj));
```

or

```
var tableobj = from table in tableOfObjects 
                 where table.ToString().Contains(objName)
                 select table;
```

Comment: @@Dhaval, thanks. I am curious why the above one fails. Any idea?